# Given by a graph is the function $f(x)$. How many solutions does $f(f(f(x)))=0$ have?

Tags: functions, contest-math

This problem, like the other ones I've posted so far, is from a 2017 olympiad. It goes like this:

Given by the following graph is the function $f(x)$:

[image]

How many solutions does $f(f(f(x)))=0$ have?

In other words, how many time does the graph of $f(f(f(x)))$ touch or intersect the x-axis?

For me, the issue already lies in identifying $f(x)$. I know it must have something to do with $|x|$. How would one go about solving this problem?

Comment: Edit: changed $f(f(f(x)))$ to $f(f(f(x)))=0$ in the title; changed y-axis to x-axis.

Comment: If you're just looking for a place to start, I woud just treat this as a middle-school graphing exercise: find $f(f(f(-1))), f(f(f(-0))),f(f(f(1)))\ldots$, put them in a table and see what happens.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry. I'd like to find e.g. $f(f(f(-1)))$, but how would I go about doing that if I don't know what this $f(x)$ entails?

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding your question correctly, but you look at -1 on the $x$ axis, and note where that point on the graph is (1). Then, you look at 1 on the $x$-axis, and see where it goes (1), then repeat a third time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! It's the first time I've used such a method, but after thinking it through, I completely understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the graph we have that:
$$f(f(f(x))=0\Leftrightarrow f(f(x))\in\{0,2\}\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in\{0,2,-2\}
\Leftrightarrow x\in\{0,2,-2,4\}.$$

P.S. Just for your curiosity: $f(x)=|x|-x+1-|x-1|$ and the graph of $f(f(f(x)))$ is[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need to obtain a different representation of $f$ besides the graph, to solve this problem.

If $f^3(x)=0$, then $f^2(x)$ must be either $0$ or $2$.

So, the problem becomes computing how many solutions are there of $f^2(x)=0$ union the solutions of $f^2(x)=2$.

For $f^2(x)=0$ we have again $f(x)=0$ or $2$. Therefore, $x=0,2$ or $-2$.

For $f^2(x)=2$ we have $f(x)=-2$, from where $x=4$.

So, in total we have $4$ solutions $x=0,x=2, x=-2$ and $x=4$.

Comment: I think $x=-2$ is the third solution lepidon intended.

Comment: If $x=4$ is a solution too, then there's four solutions, $0,\pm 2, 4$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer No, $4$, such that $f(4)=-2$, then $f^2(4)=2$ and then $f^3(4)=0$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how f(f(f(4)))=0 is not correct, @lepidon? As far as I understand, that should be a fourth solution. Thanks for answering, by the way!

Comment: @MagiDos31 It is there.